# ng-packagr gives No name was provided for external module

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

When using ng-packagr to package up one project @my/common-util, there are no problems. This class contains an abstract class called AbstractPerson in abstract-person.ts.

In another project called @my/common-impl, another Person class was created which extends AbstractPerson and imports it using @my/common-util package name. When I use ng-packagr to package it, i get the following error -->

No name was provided for external module '@my/common/abstract-person' in options.globals - guessing 'abstractPerson'

As it seemed that it was a warning, I continue to npm install both @my/common and @my/common-impl into another project, but get the following error when I import Person class from @my/common-impl

---

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@my/common-impl/esm5/common-impl.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve '@my/common/abst ract-person' in
>   'C:\Data\me\node_modules\@my\common-impl\e sm5' resolve
>   '@my/common/abstract-person' in
>   'C:\Data\me\node_modules\@my\common-impl\esm5'   Parsed request is a
>   module   using description file: C:\Data\me\node_modules\@my\co
>   mmon-impl\package.json (relative path: ./esm5)    Field 'browser'
>   doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description
>   file: C:\Data\me\node_modules\@my\common-impl\package.json (relative
>   path: ./esm5)     resolve as module

---

I have tried several things like externals, globals, umdModuleIds in package.json (see following), but none of these have worked.

Here is package.json

---

```
{
  "name": "@my/common-impl",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@my/common": "1.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  },
  "ngPackage": {
    "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "dest": "dist/common-impl",
    "workingDirectory": "../.ng_build",
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts",
      "externals": [
        "@my/common/abstract-person" 
      ],
      "globals": {
        "@my/common/abstract-person": "AbstractPerson"
      },
      "umdModuleIds": {
        "abstract-person" : "AbstractPerson"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

What further is required for this to be rectified?

Answer (score 45):

I was working with an npm module called *katex*. Adding this to the `umdModuleIds` in the **./projects/myLibname/ng-package.json** worked for me.

```json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/documentations",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "katex": "katex"
    }
  }
}
```

This made the following warning disappear

> No name was provided for external module 'katex' in output.globals – guessing 'katex'

Comment: The value for `"katex"` should be the exposed window object or default export, e.g. `"katex": "katex"`, see https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/dependencies.md#resolving-umd-module-identifiers

Comment: You are right. Anyhow using the version seems to work as well, with no errors and proper rendering. I will update my answer.

Comment: How do we find the umdmoduleid of external library?

Comment: This is the solution for external libraries but what should we do for tsconfig paths? They're not replaced when compiled.

Comment: This is for simple package name, in my case I cannot get rid of the warning for `"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome"` , I also tried `"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "fortawesome.angular-fontawesome"` and did not work!

Answer (score 3):

You should use "paths" property of `tsconfig.lib.json` in your library.

This is the issue:

I add my library1 and library2 in my [`monorepo`](https://hackernoon.com/one-vs-many-why-we-moved-from-multiple-git-repos-to-a-monorepo-and-how-we-set-it-up-f4abb0cfe469) project folder.

```
project:
   -> library1 
       -> tsconfig.lib.json
       -> ...
   -> library2 
       -> tsconfig.lib.json
       -> ...
   -> tsconfig.json 
   -> ...
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "library1": [
      "../dist/library1"
    ],
      "library2": [
      "../dist/library2"
    ],
  },
}
```

And i used `import {lib1Module} from 'library1'` in library2 code.
for resolving `no module lib1Module found` error i ovveride library1 path in library2 `tsconfig.lib.json`

`tsconfig.lib.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "library1": [
      "../../../dist/library1"
    ]
  },
  ...
},
```

Probably your issue will be resolve if you using `paths` property instead of "umdModuleIds", "globals" and "externals"

And finally i should mention this fact, "externals" no longer exist in [`ng-packagr` schema](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/blob/master/src/ng-package.schema.json).

Answer (score 1):

**In my case  I solved the warnings with this way.**

#### ng-package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/test-lib",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "@libs/shared": "../../dist/shared",
      "@libs/animations": "../../dist/animations",
      "saturn-datepicker": "saturn-datepicker",
      "moment": "moment"
    }
  }
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [ "projects/test-app/src/app/*" ],
      "@libs/*": [ "dist/*" ],
      "shared": [ "dist/shared" ],
      "shared/*": [ "dist/shared/*" ],
      "animations": [ "dist/animations" ],
      "animations/*": [ "dist/animations/*" ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the wildcard example (@libs/*) in tsconfig. However, you almost surely don't want paths in the values for umdModuleIds. Those paths will show up in your UMD js output (take a look), and you probably don't want those paths in your javascript. Instead you want the UMD global variable to match up with the UMD global variable registered in the build output of your lib - probably: "umdModuleIds": { "@libs/shared":"libs.shared" ... }